# Is there a way to bypass the PIN on Galaxy Tab a without deleting anything on it?

Tags: locked-out

I've had a Galaxy Tab a for about a year now, and I recently went out of town. When I came home and entered the security PIN, it wasn't working and then I realized that I changed it. I tried entering what I remember changing it to, but none worked. Is there a way to bypass the PIN without deleting anything on the tablet?

Comment: Did you try locking it from android.com/find? That might give u a way to change the pin depending on how old your device is

Comment: This can be done by installing a custom recovery then  manually deleting the files that hold locks data

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to reset the PIN by using your email. If your device is rooted, there are quite a lot of flashable zips for you to bypass the lockscreen on XDA.